# Powershell command runs too long

Tags: powershell

I execute the command to change the port of the printer shared on the remote printserver:

`Set-Printer -ComputerName printserver2 -Name printer10 -PortName 192.168.1.10`

The port changes after 20 seconds (I monitor it on the printserver itself), which is also not fast, but in the powershell terminal the command still runs for about 3-4 minutes.

Is it possible to track what exactly happens during the execution of the command?

Comment: You need to be an Admin.  Make sure you start PS by right click on PS shortcut and select Run As Admin.  You also may need driver name.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/printmanagement/set-printer?view=windowsserver2022-ps

Comment: It is much better when i run the command in "run as administrator" terminal window - 53.385s !

Comment: Which version of PowerShell?

Comment: you can use [Trace-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/trace-command?view=powershell-7.3) to do some debugging